# should I make a class for every page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Mostly this question is not about programming, it's like the how to use question.
and as I said above, should i make a class for every page in codeigniter? Or I can make function's for every page? if both is right, which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check CI Routing http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/routing.html

You can use 1 controller class with 20 functions for each page or you can have 4 controllers with 5 pages etc...

Comment: im just a tid bit confused by this Answer... you can use 1 controller classes with 5000000000000000 functions for each page, i dont see a limitation. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @HasoKeric its not serious for web developer to set so many functions in 1 controller, how ever if you want to make it this way its possible.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make sections/pages like..  "/widgets/view/1" or "/widgets/edit/1" or "/widgets/delete/1" your code would be:

```
class Widgets extends CI_Controller {
     public function view($id)
     {
         //Go get widget by id $id
     }

     public function edit($id)
     {

     }

     public function delete($id)
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity and similarity of your pages. If they are really alike, it could be a waste to create lots of classes, but in general I would create a class per page at least.

Comment: Answer is a touch contradictory, the "at least" at the end is the issue.